# Flutter Mapbox build keeps failing (Manifest merger failed)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to build my first application using Flutter and wanted to implement some Maps using [Mapbox GL](https://github.com/mapbox/flutter-mapbox-gl)(`mapbox_gl: ^0.0.1`).

The error I'm getting is during the building of the application. To be more precise it fails at `gradlew assembleDebug`. The output is as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

I've added the required changes to `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` as described 
[here](https://github.com/mapbox/flutter-mapbox-gl#new-project). I've also added `'tools:replace="android:value"'` suggestion but I still get the same error.

`flutter doctor` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Linux, locale en_NL.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at /path/flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (6 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /path/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /path/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /path/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 24.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Moto G 5 • android-arm • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

When I remove the Mapbox dependency in my `pubspec.yml` the build succeeds. Removing the build folder/running `flutter clean` has no result.

Has anyone else ever encountered this? I'm unable to see what I'm doing wrong here so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to study the code and see a working example, then I'd suggest for you to clone this github repo https://github.com/georific/flutter-mapbox-gl/tree/accessToken instead of https://github.com/mapbox/flutter-mapbox-gl, and follow the instruction in the readme file.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,